# SSRS Report shows two separate entries for date. Need Date then All details associated with that date

Tags: ssrs-2012

[Lines of report needed to be together under one date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHIUk.jpg)

I need the Function row to appear under the one date and not in two sets.  The row is grouped using a header.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question, for some reason the details group had disappeared.  Recreated the Tablix with the details group remaining.